# Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

Can someone help me?

My algorithm should be this:
(Note: I used DateEdit from DevExpress not DateTimePicker)

This is my output
OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit - DateEdit1
OBTADeadlineDateEdit - DateEdit2 (disable for display use only)
LiquidationDeadlineDateEdit - DateEdit3 (disable for display use only)

Example: OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit the selected date is = 12/1/2022 (you can choose any day it doesn't matter)
Display: OBTADeadlineDateEdit = 11/18/2022 (should be the 18th day of the month and before the month you chose.)
LiquidationDeadlineDateEdit = 1/5/2023 (should be the 5th day of the month and after the month you chose.)

I used this code but error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'

```
    Private Sub OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.TextChanged
       Dim dt As Date = OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.EditValue

       OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Text = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month - 1, 18)
       LiquidationDeadlineDateEdit.Text = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month + 1, 5)
    End Sub
```

Please help me regarding for this matter. thank you so much!

Comment: Would say the problem will be around dt.Month (being either 1 or 12) will no doubt give you problems.  Maybe review the [DateTime.AddMonths()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-7.0) function which will give you the correct month numbering, then construct your new dates from there.

Comment: You should have been able to see what the issue was by using the debugger. You must ALWAYS debug your code before posting a question here. Often you will be able to answer the question yourself with the information you find but, even if you can't, you can provide more relevant information to us. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn now. It is a critical skill for all developers.

Answer (score 1):

> Example: OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit the selected date is = 12/1/2022

If that's true then what do you think the value of `dt.Month - 1` will be? It will be zero. Is zero a valid month? No it is not, so that's your problem. Rather than adding or subtracting from the month value and then constructing a date, you should be constructing the date first, then adding or subtracting a month:

```vb
OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Text = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 18).AddMonths(-1)
LiquidationDeadlineDateEdit.Text = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 5).AddMonths(1)
```

EDIT:

I realised that the specified input was in US format, in which case it represents December 1st rather than January 12th. The issue is still basically the same though. It just means that the specific issue is the addition producing 13 rather than the subtraction producing zero. The solution is still the same, i.e. construct the `Date` value first, then add or subtract a month. I tested my solution like this:

```vb
Dim dt = #12/1/2022#
Dim dt1 = New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, 18).AddMonths(-1)
Dim dt2 = New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, 5).AddMonths(1)

Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToLongDateString())
Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToLongDateString())
```

and the output was:

```
Friday, 18 November 2022
Thursday, 5 January 2023
```

exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: This is error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Text = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 18).AddMonths(-1)

Comment: I misinterpreted your input but it doesn't matter. I've updated my answer based on the correct interpretation and provided a demonstration that the solution works as described. If you're still having an issue then I would suggest that your input is not what you told us it was. If you had debugged your code, as I told you in a comment and as you should already have done before posting, you'd be able to see exactly what the input was and exactly where the invalid argument is. My guess would be that `dt` is actually equal to #1/01/0001# and thus subtracting a month is not possible.